# Rearrange neural network layers in torch.nn.Sequential

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, sequential

I'm looking forward to finding a way for rearranging a sequential, because I'm trying to build a reversible convolutional neural network and I have many layers and I just want to reverse the order of layers in that sequential.
For example

```
self.features.append(nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5))
self.features.append(nn.LeakyReLU())
self.features = nn.Sequential(*self.features)
```

and then I just want to reverse that and first have activation and then convolution.
I know this sample is easy but In my case I have many layers and I can't do it by writing the reverse path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nn.Sequential(*reversed([layer for layer in original_sequential]))
```

For example:

```
>>> original_sequential = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1,6,5), nn.LeakyReLU())
>>> original_sequential
Sequential(
  (0): Conv2d(1, 6, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
  (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
)
>>> nn.Sequential(*reversed([layer for layer in original_sequential]))
Sequential(
  (0): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  (1): Conv2d(1, 6, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1))
)
```